# react: how onChange could only push one time in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
class InputTextComp  extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      validations: []
    };
  }


  handleChange(e){

     let newState = this.state;


     newState.validations.push({
         type: e.target.name,
         value: e.target.value
       });

     this.setState(...this.state, newState);

  }

  render() {

      return (
        <Form>
          <Form.Group widths='equal'>
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Placeholder</label>
              <input  name='placeholder'  onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='Placeholder' />
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Min length</label>
              <input  name='minlength'  onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='Min length' />
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Max length</label>
              <input name='maxlength'  onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='Max length' />
            </Form.Field>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
      )

  }

}
```

i have this component where i use onChange in input, i have an array in my state, array of objects, object of each input value
but when i put value in one input it push a new object like that with each change

```
validations: [
{type:'maxlength', value: '1'}, 
{type:'maxlength', value: '12'},
{type:'maxlength', value: '120'}
]
```

i want to have only one object for each input in the array like that

```
validations: [
{type:'maxlength', value: '120'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using an array for validations, you should use a hash

`validations: {
  placeholder: '',
  minlength: '',
  maxlength: ''
}`

then the `onChange` can set the respective validation with the lastest change.

`newState[e.target.name] = e.target.value`

Comment: i know it would be easier to use object but i really need validations to be an array cause each object has it own info like {type: 'minlength', value: 1, meassage: 'min length is 1'}

Comment: why couldnt you just do this then?


validations: {
  placeholder: { message: 'min length is 1', value: 1' },
  minlength: { message: 'min length is 1', value: 1' },
  maxlength: { message: 'min length is 1', value: 1' }
}